# Parsing SMTLIB using the Z3 C API without losing `push`, `pop` and `check-sat` commands

Tags: z3, smt, smt-lib

I'm using the `Z3_parse_smtlib2_string` function from the Z3 C API (via [Haskell's Z3 lib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3)) to parse an SMTLIB file and apply some tactics to simplify its content, however I notice that any `push`, `pop` and `check-sat` commands appear to be swallowed by this function and do not appear in the resulting AST.

Is there anyway that I can parse this without losing these commands (and then apply the required tactics, once again without losing them)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this with `Z3_parse_smtlib2_string`. As you can see in the documentation "It returns a formula comprising of the conjunction of assertions in the scope (up to push/pop) at the end of the string." See: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/group__capi.html#ga7905ebec9289b9fe5debcad965f6267e

Note that the reason for this is not just mere "not-implemented" or  "buggy." Look at the return type of the function you're using. It returns a `Z3_ast_vector`, and `Z3_ast` only captures "expressions" in the SMTLib language. But `push`/`pop` etc. are not considered expressions by Z3, but rather commands; i.e., they are internally represented differently. (Whether this was a conscious choice or historical is something I'm not sure about.)

I don't think there's a function to do what you're asking; i.e., can return both expressions and commands. You can ask at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/discussions to see if the developers can provide an alternative API, or if they already have something exposed to the users that achieves this.